# select内に入れるとdata属性が効かないのでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, html, css

ドロップダウンに項目を入れようとして、selectを使用したところ結果が表示されなくなります。
divの時は動いていたので何か問題があるのだと思うのですが、何が問題なのかがわかりません。
何か足りない部分があるのでしょうか<(_ _)>

```html
       <select>
            <option value="all" data-filter="all" class="is-active">全て表示</option>
            <option value="a" data-filter="a">A</option>
            <option value="b" data-filter="b">B</option>
            <option value="c" data-filter="c">C</option>
        </select>

        <ul class="genre">
            <li data-genre="a">A+A</li>
            <li data-genre="a-b">A+B</li>
            <li data-genre="a-c">A+C</li>
            <li data-genre="b">B+B</li>
            <li data-genre="b-c">B+C</li>
            <li data-genre="c">C+C</li>
        </ul>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
const filterButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-filter]");
const genreContents = document.querySelectorAll("[data-genre]");

filterButtons.forEach((filterButton) => {
    filterButton.addEventListener("click", buttonSwitch);
    filterButton.addEventListener("click", genreFilter);
});

function buttonSwitch() {
    filterButtons.forEach((filterButton) => {
        filterButton.classList.remove("is-active");
        this.classList.add("is-active");
    });
}

function genreFilter() {
    const buttongenre = this.dataset.filter;

    const targetContents = document.querySelectorAll('[data-genre*="' + buttongenre + '"]');

    genreContents.forEach((genreContent) => {
        genreContent.animate(
            [
                {
                    opacity: 0,
                },
                {
                    opacity: 1,
                },
            ],
            {
                duration: 600,
                fill: "forwards",
            }
        );

        if (buttongenre == "all") {
            genreContent.classList.add("is-show");
        } else {
            genreContent.classList.remove("is-show");
            targetContents.forEach((targetContent) => {
                targetContent.classList.add("is-show");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`:has()`疑似クラス](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/:has)を使うとCSSセレクターに条件を設定することができます。[`:checked`疑似クラス](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/:checked)はチェックボックスやラジオボタンだけでなく、現在選択されている`option`要素にも適用されます。
記述としては冗長になってしまいますが、JavaScriptと違って静的に定義できるところが利点です。
ただし、現時点でFirefoxが正式対応できていないことに注意してください（対応がずるずる伸びてる…）。

```css
body ul.genre li {
  opacity: 0;
}

body:has(select option:checked[data-filter="all"]) ul.genre li,
body:has(select option:checked[data-filter="a"]) ul.genre li[data-genre*="a"],
body:has(select option:checked[data-filter="b"]) ul.genre li[data-genre*="b"],
body:has(select option:checked[data-filter="c"]) ul.genre li[data-genre*="c"] {
  animation: 600ms forwards genre;
}

@keyframes genre {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="all" data-filter="all" class="is-active">全て表示</option>
  <option value="a" data-filter="a">A</option>
  <option value="b" data-filter="b">B</option>
  <option value="c" data-filter="c">C</option>
</select>

<ul class="genre">
  <li data-genre="a">A+A</li>
  <li data-genre="a-b">A+B</li>
  <li data-genre="a-c">A+C</li>
  <li data-genre="b">B+B</li>
  <li data-genre="b-c">B+C</li>
  <li data-genre="c">C+C</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ありがとうございます(*>人<)
動きました！
ただ・・・opacity: 0;の場合は要素が消えているだけで、行間が出来てしまうんですけど、これは詰める事が出来るのでしょうか？(*>人<)

display: none・・・は無理ですよね？(T_T)

Comment: @aruchiman それは「select内に入れるとdata属性が効かない」とは無関係な話題です。本件を解決済みにして新たに質問するとよいかと。もしかして`is-show`クラスが関係しているのでしょうか？ そうなら質問文に`is-show`クラスの定義も含めてください。

Answer (score 1):

多くのブラウザでは、メニュー `<select>` 内の `<option>` では `click` イベントが発生しません。「`<option>` はページに表示されているわけではなく、 `<select>`にデータを与えているだけ」という扱いになるようです。`<option>` に対するスタイルシートもほとんど無効になります。

`<select>` の `change` イベントなどで変更を検知するように変更する必要があります。質問文のコードだとそこそこの量のコードを書き換える必要がありそうですね。

以下のような変更が必要かと思います:

- `forEach()` ですべての `<option>` にリスナを登録するのではなく、`<select>` の `change` イベントに `buttonSwitch` と `genreFilter` を登録する
- `buttonSwitch()` と `genreFilter()` の中では、`this` のかわりに `this.selectedOptions[0]` を利用する

`is-active` のスタイルは効かないかもしれません。

Comment: イベントが発生するようにＪＳを書き換えないといけないと言う事ですね・・・
他の要素では動いていたのでやはりそこが原因なんですね
項目が増えそうだったのでselectを使用してすっきりさせたかったんですが、流石に初心者の知識ではできそうもないので諦める方向で考えます(*ᴗˬᴗ)⁾⁾⁾

Comment: 具体的にどのような変更が必要かを回答に書いてみました。

Comment: this.selectedOption を利用する場合data-genre*部分のあいまい検索は使えなくなる感じでしょうか？(*>人<)

Comment: `const targetContents =` 以降のコードは無変更で機能するはずです。機能しないならどこかで間違えているのでしょう。

Comment: おっと失礼しました。`this.selectedOption` ではなく `this.selectedOptions[0]` とする必要がありますね